# Difference in behaviour of node.js Event loop for In-built and custom events

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading about event loops in node.js. As per my read through various articles and posts in stackexchange, I got that **all the callbacks are appended at the end of the task queue, and after the execution of the main file, all the tasks in the queue are executed sequentially**. I tried to confirm it by a small program. There I found a strange behavior. Below is the content of the main.js file I created.

```
//Declare file open event handler
var fs = require("fs");
var ws = fs.createWriteStream("C:\\test.txt");
ws.on("open", function(fd) {
    console.log("#Event file 'open'");
});

//Wait for 5 seconds
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log("Give time of 5 seconds to get file opened (being conservative)...\n");
while(new Date().getTime() - startTime < 5000) {}

//Create custom event
var util = require("util");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var CustomEventEmitter = function() {};
util.inherits(CustomEventEmitter, EventEmitter);

//Declare custom event handler
var customInstance = new CustomEventEmitter();
customInstance.on("tick", function() {
    console.log("#Event custom 'tick'");
});

//Emit custom event
customInstance.emit("tick");

console.log("#End 'main.js'");
```

It gave me the following output:

```
Give time of 5 seconds to get file opened (being conservative)...

#Event custom 'tick'
#End 'main.js'
#Event file 'open'
```

The log "#Event file 'open'" is outputted after "#End 'main.js'", but how come the log "#Event custom 'tick'" came first, if it was supposed to be in the task queue.

I mean how come in-built event is showing proper behavior, and custom event did not?

Please correct my understanding on this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing is that `emitter.emit()` is synchronous.

Here's what's happening, step by step:

- When you call `fs.createWriteStream()`, that calls an async function which gets put in the task queue for processing after the current tick is over.
- Then your `while` loop happens for five seconds, which has no effect on the order of events firing, as we'll see.
- Next you emit your `tick` event. Cool. `emit()` is synchronous and fires the listeners, so: **#Event custom 'tick' logs here**
- Your main function ends. **#End 'main.js' logs here.**
- Node takes the function (that was placed on the task queue by `createWriteStream()` off the task queue. This eventually results in the `open` event firing, result in: **#Event file 'open' logs here**

So that's why things appear in that order.

Comment: hmm...I had exactly this in my mind, and as per this understanding the output order should have been like: 
#End 'main.js' 
#Event file 'open' 
#Event custom 'tick' 
......main.js should have been first line, and custom tick should have been last...correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Oh, I missed that `emit()` is not asynchronous. Updated. It now explains your output correctly, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it... You're right that, it's because the emit function is synchronous([link](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/10e31ba56c676bdcad39ccad22ea9117733b8eb5/lib/events.js#L67)) and so the event handler is called synchronously. It doesn't put the handler function into event queue...

Answer (score 0):

when you traverse a while loop like you did, you basically hijack the thread and peg the CPU for 5 seconds. Try the same test with setInterval or setTimeout. SetTimeout/Interval will allow the js engine to execute other tasks between loops. Even if you give it 1ms as a gap, that is enough for the engine to clear its queue.

(Further clarification - edit)

Javascript will put callbacks at the very back of the stack. So if you stick a whole bunch of sequential statements in some routine, they all have to finish before your file callback can get in the back of the line.

In the case of your custom event, that was not something async, so it actually behaves the same seemingly strange way that your while counter did. The thread kept executing statements in sequence because of the nature of the CustomEventEmitter. You will see this in jQuery click events on the browser also. It is synchronous, so all of the event handler statements are ahead in the event loop.

So knowing whether something executes async or not is what will help in understanding js code flow. The while loop and the CustomEventEmitter are both synchronous operations, while the fs is async.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I appreciate your effort...but I was looking for the reason of  the log order to understand event-loop better. I know setInterval and setTimeout will work perfectly, but for this program as per my understanding, the output log should have been: #End 'main.js' #Event file 'open' #Event custom 'tick'....which is not showing up.

Comment: Well, I saw you wanted to "give 5 seconds to get the file opened". I wanted to make sure you knew that the js engine could do _nothing else_ while that while loop was running. That actually fully explains while the very soonest gap in the event loop was after #End. All those statements were in the loop first, so the open had to happen afterwards.

Comment: you're right Ron, the open log order is fine, it is as expected. But I am wondering about the custom tick event log. Why it's coming first? It should have been somewhere after #End, and not before #End...

Comment: Yes, I have clarified for you in the answer above. Hope it helps :)